# c++ getting values one by one from a file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I know this kind of questions appear many times stackoverflow  however I couldnt find a good answer to my question. I've tried to figure out how could I get values one bye one from a file in c++. Let me explain it :

```
test.txt

1 1 0.5
31 5 14
```

I want to store 1,1,0.5 in my vector or array and make some process on it and after that,getting the second line and make same operations again. Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just saying "I couldn't find a good answer" is not an excuse for asking this yet again. What have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

C++ way to achieve this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   std::string line;
   std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");

   while ( std::getline( ifs, line ) ) {
      std::istringstream is( line );
      std::vector<double> numbers = std::vector<double>
                               ( std::istream_iterator<double>(is),
                                 std::istream_iterator<double>());
      //... f(numbers);
      // i.e:
      // std::copy( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
      //            std::ostream_iterator<double>( std::cout, " "));
   }
}
```

Comment: It needs to use `double` not `int` but otherwise this is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line to strings and then splits strings and add them to vector like below:

```
std::string delimiter = " ";
vector <string> v;
std::string s = "1 1 0.5" // a line from file
size_t pos = 0;

std::string token;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    v.push_back(token);
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```